# Sending mail, getting ActionView::MissingTemplate <path> with 'mailer'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer, sidekiq, mailer

When trying to send emails with Sidekiq, I am getting this error

> ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template campaign_mailer/hugh_email with "mailer". Searched in: * "campaign_mailer"

In the controller

```
CampaignMailer.hugh_email(email, user).deliver_later
```

In campaign_mailer.rb

```
layout 'mailer'

def hugh_email(email, user)
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: email.subject)
end
```

`app/views/campaign_mailer/hugh_email.html.slim` has the html, and I have a template in `layouts/mailer`

**Note:** I have tried everything I can find, even re-generated mailers. It seems to work with a new mailer when I send with `deliver_now`, but as soon as I try `deliver_later` the error returns (even when going back to trying a `deliver_now`).

**UPDATE:**

My solution to this probably won't help many people, but I'll add it here just in case.

I now save the emails on my system, and pass the html into the mailer with `CampaignMailer.hugh_email(email.subject, html).deliver_later`. In the `campaign_mailer.rb` I run

```
mail(to: to_address, subject: email_subject) do |format|
      format.text { render(text: "") }
      format.html { html }
    end
```

Again, unfortunately this probably won't help most people having this issue. But I essentially solved the problem by specifying the html instead of using the mailer view.

Answer (score 0):

**hugh_email.html.slim** must be at

```
/app/views/campaign_mailer/hugh_email.html.slim
```

**mailer.html.slim** at

```
/app/views/layouts/mailer.html.slim
```

**mailer.text.erb** at

```
/app/views/layouts/mailer.text.erb
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that this is the path for my html file. I updated to question to refer to this, thanks.

Comment: I was missing `mailer.text.erb` so I added it and restarted everything (rails, sidekiq, redis, flushed the Q). Still no luck.

Comment: @ChrisBrisson any updates of your question then please post here.. as I am facing same issue. Thanks.